# Не могу завершить FSM (машину состояний)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Ошибка:

> await state.finish()
>
> NameError: name 'state' is not defined

Код:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
import sqlite3 as sq


db = sq.connect('usersList.db')
db.close()

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token=conf.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot,storage=storage)

class Mailing(StatesGroup): #state of mailing

    text = State()
    photo = State()
    confirmation = State()

@dp.message_handler(user_id = 889768244, commands=['sendingMessage']) #command for mailing
async def sendingMessageActivator(msg: types.Message):
    await Mailing.text.set()
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Пришли текст рассылки")

@dp.message_handler(user_id = 889768244,state=Mailing.text) #getting text for mailing
async def adminMsg(msg: types.Message):
    waitingMessage = msg.text
    print(waitingMessage,msg.text)
    await Mailing.photo.set()
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Пришли фото рассылки")
@dp.message_handler(user_id = 889768244,state=Mailing.photo, content_types="photo") #getting photo for mailing
async def adminMsg(msg: types.message):
    waitingPhoto = msg.photo[-1].file_id
    print(waitingMessage, msg.text)
    await bot.send_photo(msg.from_user.id,waitingPhoto,caption=waitingMessage)
    await Mailing.confirmation.set()
    print(waitingMessage)



@dp.message_handler(user_id = 889768244,state=Mailing.confirmation)
async def confirmation(msg: types.Message):
#подтверждение    
await state.finish()
```

Comment: Во-первых у вас явно не хватает табуляции в той строчке, где ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не передали аргумент `state`. Вместо

```py
async def confirmation(msg: types.Message):
```

Нужно так:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

...
 
async def confirmation(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
```